# How to enter usb accessory mode via code?

Tags: java, android, usb

Hi I have to create and android application that put the device in usb accessory mode.
Is there a way to do that?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you just aking for discussion or did you code and got stuck  ?

Comment: @cantona_7 I'm asking for discussion, I have to build that app but I don't know where to start from

Comment: okie. What exactly you want ? you should add little bit more info.

Comment: have a look here. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory#java

Comment: @cantona_7 the app should be very simple: I open it and automatically it put my device into accessory mode. That's it